# Dashboard chart - show last seven days by default

Tags: magento-1.9, dashboard

Magento admin dashboard chart shows last 24 hours stats by default.

How to show last 7 days by default instead?

Is this possible without overriding core files?

Comment: visit link::-http://greladesign.com/blog/2011/06/06/modify-admin-dashboards-default-period-time-select-range/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rewrite the method `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Graph::_prepareData`.
by default it looks like this:

```
protected function _prepareData()
{
    $availablePeriods = array_keys($this->helper('adminhtml/dashboard_data')->getDatePeriods());
    $period = $this->getRequest()->getParam('period');
    $this->getDataHelper()->setParam('period',
        ($period && in_array($period, $availablePeriods)) ? $period : '24h'
    );
}
```

You need to replace `24h` with `7d`.